# Enabling multiple filters for a single array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter

in my application, there are two types of filters, category and country. However, I am not able to get them to be applied at the same time. For example, I only want the intersection of Category: SaaS + Country: Singapore.

Any advice?

```
  const loadData = props.load 
  const [card, setCard] = useState(loadData)
  const [searchPhrase, setSearchPhrase] = useState("")
  const search = (event)=>{
    const matchedUsers = loadData.filter((card)=>{
      return card.title.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
    })
    setCard(matchedUsers)
    setSearchPhrase(event.target.value)
  }
  const filterCountry = (event)=>{
    const filteredCards = loadData.filter((card)=>{
      return card.country.includes(event.target.value)
    })
    setCard(filteredCards)
  }
  const filterCat = (event)=>{
    const filteredCards = loadData.filter((card)=>{
      return card.cat.includes(event.target.value)
    })
    setCard(filteredCards)
  }
```

Comment: How about maintaining all the search inputs in a state and comparing the array against all the criteria?

Comment: how can i do that? @Rayon

Comment: 1. Update the state when input is changed 2. Use `useEffect` over the state values 3. As you have all the input values, you can filter the array considering all the filter parameters.

Comment: You should probably store all the filters in a state, and then filteredCards should just be a memoized filtered `loadData` based on the filter(s) in your state.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your filter condition to check if the value is in all your considered types

```
const result = yourData.filter(item => item.country.includes(YOURPHRASE) || item.cat.includes(YOURPHRASE))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the filtered array as a parameter to the filtering functions :

```
 const search = (event)=>{
       const matchedUsers = loadData.filter((card)=>{
          return card.title.toLowerCase().includes(event.target.value.toLowerCase())
        })
        setSearchPhrase(event.target.value);
return matchedUsers
      }
      

const filterCountry = (event,array)=>{
   
    return array.filter((card) => card.country.includes(event.target.value);

  }

 const filterCat = (event,array)=>{
        return array.filter((card) => card.cat.includes(event.target.value);
  }
        
     useEffect(() => {
        
        let result = matchedUsers();
        result = filterCountry(result);
        result = filterCat(result);
        setArrayToFilter(result);
    }, [searchPhrase]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this but it says: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')